# No qualifying bean of type,expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire, org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I Created a simple Springboot Application with H2 DB. Not able to start the spring boot Application getting below error on startup. I have added all the necessary configurations.

> Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling
> refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'studentController': Unsatisfied
> dependency expressed through field 'studentService'; nested exception
> is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'com.example.test.serviceimpl.StudentServiceImpl' available: expected
> at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency
> annotations:
> {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Controller:

```java
package com.example.test.controller;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import com.example.test.serviceimpl.StudentServiceImpl;
import comm.example.test.model.Student;

@RestController
public class StudentController {
  
  @Autowired(required=true)
  private StudentServiceImpl studentService;
  
  @GetMapping("/student")  
  private List<Student> getAllStudent() {  
    return studentService.getAllStudent();  
  } 
  
  @GetMapping("/student/{id}")  
  private Student getStudent(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {  
    return studentService.getStudentById(id);  
  }  
}
```

Student Pojo class

```java
package comm.example.test.model;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;

@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="student")
public class Student {
  @Id   
  @Column  
  private Long id;  
  
  @Column  
  private String name;  
  
  @Column  
  private int age;  
  
  @Column  
  private String email;
}
```

StudentService Interface:

```java
package com.example.test.service;

import java.util.List;
import comm.example.test.model.Student;

public interface StudentService {
  List<Student> getAllStudent();
  Student getStudentById(Long id); 
}
```

StudentServiceImpl:

```java
package com.example.test.serviceimpl;

import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.example.test.repository.serviceimpl.StudentRepositoryServiceImpl;
import com.example.test.service.StudentService;
import comm.example.test.model.Student;

public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

  @Autowired
  private StudentRepositoryServiceImpl serviceImpl;

  @Override
  public List<Student> getAllStudent() {
    return serviceImpl.getAllStudent();
  }

  @Override
  public Student getStudentById(Long id) {
    return serviceImpl.getStudentById(id);
  } 
}
```

RepositoryService:

```java
package com.example.test.repository.serviceimpl;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import com.example.test.repository.StudentRepository;
import comm.example.test.model.Student;

@Service
public class StudentRepositoryServiceImpl {

  @Autowired
  private StudentRepository repo;
  
  public List<Student> getAllStudent() {  
    List<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();  
    repo.findAll().forEach(student -> students.add(student));  
    return students;  
  } 

  public Student getStudentById(Long id) {  
    return repo.findById(id).get();  
  } 
}
```

Repository:

```java
package com.example.test.repository;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import comm.example.test.model.Student;

@Repository
public interface StudentRepository extends JpaRepository<Student, Long> {

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your `StudentServiceImpl` needs a `@Service` annotation to be injected.